# Stop my HTML button from leaving the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is probably really simple but googling didn't help me. So I have a robot attached to the network and it responds to queries on an URL eg http://172.16.0.1:8001/web/Speed?Speed1=100

All i want to do is make a few simple buttons which will send these queries but won't leave the page. At the moment I have the following HTML which works but every time I press a button it goes to the URL in question and leaves the main page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

    <strong>MyRIO Robot Controller</strong>


    <input type=button onClick="parent.location='http://172.16.0.1:8001/web/connect?Connect=1'" value='Start Control'>
    <input type=button onClick="parent.location='http://172.16.0.1:8001/web/connect?Connect=0'" value='Stop Control'>
    <input type=button onClick="parent.location='http://172.16.0.1:8001/web/Speed?Speed1=100'" value='Full Speed'>
    <input type=button onClick="parent.location='http://172.16.0.1:8001/web/Speed?Speed1=50'" value='Half Speed'>
    <input type=button onClick="parent.location='http://172.16.0.1:8001/web/Speed?Speed1=00'" value='Stop'>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't want to POST or GET when clicking the buttons, you'll have to do AJAX.

Comment: Ajax is your solution as long as it is on the same domain, else including the page as a iframe is also possible.

Comment: Okay I am getting somewhere now, do you have an example of some AJAX I could use (I don't even know what AJAX is but I am willing to learn)

Comment: there are lots of tutorials on ajax .... let google be your friend

Answer (score 0):

So AJAX wasn't that hard to learn it seems. for anyone else having this problem here is the solution I came up with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function startControl()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://172.16.0.1:8001/web/connect?Connect=1",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    function stopControl()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://172.16.0.1:8001/web/connect?Connect=0",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>MyRIO Robot Controller</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="startControl()">Start Control</button>
<button type="button" onclick="stopControl()">Stop Control</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```